# Google Calendar sending the same SMS each day at a specified time

Tags: google-calendar, sms

How can I set Google Calendar to send me the same SMS Daily (or every Thursday or after every 45 Days) at a specified time?

If this is not possible in Google Calender, then is there any other Web App that has this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[IFTTT](http://ifttt.com/) is great for stuff like this. The `Date & Time` channel is the one you're looking for.

[image]